# Selecting linked image by same attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to make a light box pop up from some linked images, but I have no control over its id or class, these come from an SMF forum.

I need to compare linked images to see if their `src` and `href` attributes are the same, and then use the light box plugin.

I managed to get this in the document ready function:

```
$('a.bbc_link:has(img.resized)').lightboxplugin();
```

This makes all images launch the lightbox plugin, but I need to compare the `img` src and the link `href` to see if they are the same, and then use the plugin.

Sadly, it has to be made with jQuery, which I have little experience with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the links, and apply the lightbox plugin there:

```
$('a.bbc_link').each(function(){
    var linkHref = $(this).attr('href');
    var imgSrc = $(this).find('img.resized').attr('src');
    // Compare and apply plugin as needed...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, first tests go well, i have to learn more of jquery asap.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
 $('a.bbc_link:has(img.resized)').each(function(index) {

      if($(this).attr('src') == $(this).attr('href') ){ //Compare link to URL
           $(this).lightboxplugin();
      }

 });
```